# Using the SocialFeedManager object in Remote Event Receiver

Tags: 2013, event-receivers, sharepoint-addin, remote-event-receiver

I'm trying to create a Remote Event Receiver that will update the social feed of a user when ever he adds an item to a list on SharePoint Online. I've initiated the client context object using the code from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2013-Use-event-8b5a551f/sourcecode?fileId=72211&pathId=989899932.

Whenever i try to initiate the `SocialFeedManager` inside the using statement as such:

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(sharepointUrl.ToString(), accessToken))
            {
                SocialFeedManager feedManager = new SocialFeedManager(clientContext);
                writeToList(properties, "RemoteEventLog", "got feedmanager");
            }
```

I never get to the `writeToList` method. If i remove the `SocialFeedManager` initiation the `writeToList` method gets called just fine.

To make matters even worse, if i try to debug my Remote Event Receiver it works just fine, its only when i deploy it that it refuses to work with the `SocialFeedManager`.

Comment: good question :)

Comment: I'm facing the same issue with PeopleManager class. Is there any known limitation using social api inside remote event recievers?

Comment: Only solution i found was using the REST API instead.. works great.